# Windows Store Pull to Display button

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I've got a Windows runtime app setup displaying a long ListView which I want a user to be able to refresh.

I have currently placed a refresh button in the header of the ListView but this isn't ideal as it is always displayed.

I want the user to be able to pull down on the ListView and as the view scrolls down a button which can be tapped to refresh is scrolled into view. However by default the ListView snaps to keep this out of view above the ListViewItems.

How do I get the ScrollViewer to display this by default above the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the user to be able to pull down and to show the button which can then be tapped.

If I understand your request correctly you want to have an [App Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781232.aspx) which can be invoked by either pressing the Right Mouse button or swiping in from the bottom or top of the App.

The AppBar itself, or rather the containing `CommandBar` can also be configured to be displayed as soon as the user navigates to the Page/View by using the `IsOpen` attribute

```xml
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsOpen="True">
        <AppBarButton Label="Refresh" Icon="Refresh" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Label="Help" Icon="Help" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the idea I was going after. I have updated the question to try more accurately reflect what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that. You could still go with the AppBar/CommandBar approach. That is something commong I see across many WP Apps that they hide their ListView actions inside the AppBar